# How to loop a <List<Dictionary<string, object>>> of Json.net to convert an excel file using EPPUS

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net, epplus-4

How to loop a `<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>` of Json.net to convert an excel file using EPPUS

```
var resposneJson1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(parametroJson);
```

I have to retrieve the names of the fields to create the excel headers and then create the rows with the values.

[image: My dictionary]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the values of type object in the dictionary, is it simply a string or a complex object?

Comment: Is a complex object